# How to remove and replace the label everytime the button is pressed | TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

For my program, when I click "SHOW SELECTION" after selecting from the dropdown menu, the label shows the result. But when I do it again, it will write the next label in bottom of the first label and so on and so forth.
The code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title('First Window')
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/themr/Downloads/avatar_referee_man_sport_game_icon_228558.ico')
root.geometry("400x400")

var = StringVar()
var.set("Monday")

drop = OptionMenu(root, var, "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
drop.pack()


def show():
    label = Label(root, text=var.get())
    label.pack()


button = Button(root, text="Show Selection", command=show)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I actually want is that the new label should replace the first one and so there is only one line shown no matter how many times I press the button.

Please help out!

Comment: Why do you want to remove and replace the label? Are you aware that you can change the text without destroying and recreating the widget?

Comment: No I am not, Can you please share?

Comment: There is an answer that explains how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy fix. What you're currently doing is creating a new label each time `show` is called. And you don't need to remove and replace the label each time. All you have to do is instantiate the label with an empty text and then use `.config` to change its text.

```
root = Tk()
root
root.title("First Window")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/themr/Downloads/avatar_referee_man_sport_game_icon_228558.ico')
root.geometry("400x400")

var = StringVar()
var.set("Monday")

drop = OptionMenu(
    root,
    var,
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
)
drop.pack()


def show():
    # when show is called, change the label's text
    label.config(text=var.get())


my_button = Button(root, text="Show selection", command=show)

# label starts with an empty text
label = Label(root, text="")

my_button.pack()
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```